# Java unicode question

Tags: java, unicode

This may be a silly question but... Say I have a `String` like `4e59` which represents a special unicode character. How can I add the `\u` to the beginning of that character so that it displays correctly? I've tried the simplest solution of:

```
String str = "4e59";
System.out.println("\\u"+str);
```

And several other variants, what am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The \u is parsed at compile time, not run time, so just prefixing your string with "\u" isn't going to work.

You can use Integer.parseInt to do this parsing at runtime:

```
System.out.println((char)Integer.parseInt("4e59", 16));
```

Comment: In case brandon was interested, this also works:
char c = 0x4E59;

Answer (score 5):

Others have already answered with how to do this, but if you're interested I can explain why prepending `"\u"` didn't work: the `"\uXXXX"` sequences are converted to the corresponding unicode character at compile time by javac (by the lexer, which is the first step in compilation, in fact). In your code, the lexer sees a string containing just `"\u"` and so doesn't touch it.

The `\uXXXX` encoding will work anywhere, not just inside strings. Both of these lines are identical if you put them in a Java source file:

```
int i;

\u0069\u006E\u0074 \u0069\u003B
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert it to a `char`:

```
System.out.println((char) Integer.parseInt("4e59", 16));
```

Comment: Integer.valueOf() returns an Integer object, which then needs to be converted to an int, (and then into a char), which is kind of extraneous. Integer.parseInt() returns an int directly

Comment: That's true. I've changed my answer.